# How to set up the hello world webpart for Sharepoint 2019, using Share point framework v1.4.1

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts, spfx, sharepoint-2019

I followed Microsoft's instructions for building my first hello world web part for sharepoint 2019 found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/sharepoint-2019-and-subscription-edition-support) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/build-a-hello-world-web-part).  Everything has worked up until the "To get access to the page context" section of [part 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/connect-to-sharepoint)

I pasted the code and save the files and my gulp is giving the following errors:

[gulp errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZFoR.png)

Does anyone have an idea why this is happening?  When I hover my mouse over the errors in VS code it shows this: [errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TuyBd.png)

I also tried the next part in the tutorial which is "Retrieve lists from SharePoint site" and I get a problem with the return statement in the function:[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nIa9j.png)

I see others online following the same exact tutorial with the same exact code, yet theirs does not throw these errors.  My guess is because I am using such old versions to work with SharePoint 2019? For instance, as instructed by Microsoft, in order to develop web parts for SharePoint 2019 I had to get SharePoint Framework v1.4.1 and I am also using node version 8.17.0.

I will paste my entire HelloWorldWebPart.ts file here:

```
import { Version } from '@microsoft/sp-core-library';
import {
  BaseClientSideWebPart,
  IPropertyPaneConfiguration,
  PropertyPaneTextField,
  PropertyPaneCheckbox,
  PropertyPaneDropdown,
  PropertyPaneToggle
} from '@microsoft/sp-webpart-base';
import { escape } from '@microsoft/sp-lodash-subset';

import styles from './HelloWorldWebPart.module.scss';
import * as strings from 'HelloWorldWebPartStrings';
import {
  SPHttpClient,
  SPHttpClientResponse
} from '@microsoft/sp-http';

export interface IHelloWorldWebPartProps {
  description: string;
  test: string;
  test1: boolean;
  test2: string;
  test3: boolean;
}

export interface ISPLists {
  value: ISPList[];
}

export interface ISPList {
  Title: string;
  Id: string;
}
export default class HelloWorldWebPart extends BaseClientSideWebPart<IHelloWorldWebPartProps> {

  public render(): void {
    this.domElement.innerHTML = `
    <section class="${styles.helloWorld} ${!!this.context.sdks.microsoftTeams ? styles.teams : ''}">
      <div class="${styles.welcome}">
        <img alt="" src="${this._isDarkTheme ? require('./assets/welcome-dark.png') : require('./assets/welcome-light.png')}" class="${styles.welcomeImage}" />
        <h2>Well done, ${escape(this.context.pageContext.user.displayName)}!</h2>
        <div>${this._environmentMessage}</div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h3>Welcome to SharePoint Framework!</h3>
        <div>Web part description: <strong>${escape(this.properties.description)}</strong></div>
        <div>Web part test: <strong>${escape(this.properties.test)}</strong></div>
        <div>Loading from: <strong>${escape(this.context.pageContext.web.title)}</strong></div>
      </div>
</section>`;
  }

  protected get dataVersion(): Version {
    return Version.parse('1.0');
  }

  protected getPropertyPaneConfiguration(): IPropertyPaneConfiguration {
    return {
      pages: [
        {
          header: {
            description: strings.PropertyPaneDescription
          },
          groups: [
            {
              groupName: strings.BasicGroupName,
              groupFields: [
              PropertyPaneTextField('description', {
                label: 'Description'
              }),
              PropertyPaneTextField('test', {
                label: 'Multi-line Text Field',
                multiline: true
              }),
              PropertyPaneCheckbox('test1', {
                text: 'Checkbox'
              }),
              PropertyPaneDropdown('test2', {
                label: 'Dropdown',
                options: [
                  { key: '1', text: 'One' },
                  { key: '2', text: 'Two' },
                  { key: '3', text: 'Three' },
                  { key: '4', text: 'Four' }
                ]}),
              PropertyPaneToggle('test3', {
                label: 'Toggle',
                onText: 'On',
                offText: 'Off'
              })
            ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    };
  }
  private _getListData(): Promise<ISPLists> {
    return this.context.spHttpClient.get(`${this.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl}/_api/web/lists?$filter=Hidden eq false`, SPHttpClient.configurations.v1)
      .then((response: SPHttpClientResponse) => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .catch(() => {});
  }

}
```